Prune function for decision tree
I am creating a decision tree from scratch and implementing pruning. Currently I believe the problem in my code is that when I prune a tree, the new leaf node I create does not get placed into the original tree, so when I calculate the new accuracy, it is valid and all my branches get pruned. Attached is my code for the tree class, leaf class and pruning function.
My issue is that the new leaf node I create to attempt pruning does not seem to reflect in the original tree when attempt to calculate the new accuracy.
How can I fix/restructure my code so that the pruning updates the current tree, and so when I calculate the new accuracy, the pruning can be determined to be successful or not?
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, feature, split, depth, left = None, right = None):
        """
            self.feature = the feature the node splits upon
            self.split = the value the of the feature the node splits upon
            self.left = the left child
            self.right = the right child
            self.depth = depth of the tree at this point
        """
        self.feature = feature
        self.split = split
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.depth = depth

    def getLeft(self):
        return self.left
    
    def getRight(self):
        return self.right
    
    def getFeature(self):
        return self.feature
    
    def getSplit(self):
        return self.split
    
    def getDepth(self):
        return self.depth

    def eval(self, sample):
        if sample[self.feature] < self.split:
            return self.left.eval(sample)
        else:
            return self.right.eval(sample)
        
class LeafNode:
    def __init__(self, roomNumber, users, depth):
        """
            self.roomNumer = the room number that the leaf is assigned
            self.depth = depth of the leaf in the tree
        """
        self.roomNumber = roomNumber
        self.depth = depth
        self.users = users

    def getRoomNumber(self):
        return self.roomNumber
                
    def getDepth(self):
        return self.depth
    
    def getUsers(self):
        return self.users
    
    def eval(self, sample):
        self.users += 1
        return self.getRoomNumber()

def pruneTree(original_tree, validation, node):
    if node is None:
        return None
    if isinstance(node, LeafNode):
        return node
    node.left = pruneTree(original_tree, validation, node.left)
    node.right = pruneTree(original_tree, validation, node.right)
    if isinstance(node.left, LeafNode) and isinstance(node.right, LeafNode):

        current_accuracy = evaluate(validation, original_tree)

        leftRoom, leftPopulation = node.left.getRoomNumber(), node.left.getUsers()

        rightRoom, rightPopulation = node.right.getRoomNumber(), node.right.getUsers()

        previous_feature, previous_split, previous_depth, previous_left, previous_right = node.getFeature(), node.getSplit(), node.getDepth(), node.getLeft(), node.getRight()

        newRoom = -1

        newPopulation = leftPopulation + rightPopulation

        if rightPopulation >= leftPopulation:
            newRoom = rightRoom
        else:
            newRoom = leftRoom

        node = LeafNode(roomNumber = newRoom, users=newPopulation, depth = previous_depth)

        new_accuracy = evaluate(validation, original_tree)
        
        if new_accuracy < current_accuracy:
            node = TreeNode(split = previous_split, feature=previous_feature, depth=previous_depth)
            node.left = previous_left
            node.right = previous_right
    return node

def evaluate(test_db, trained_tree):
    num_correct = 0
    for data in test_db:
        sample = data[:-1]
        prediction = trained_tree.eval(sample)

        if prediction == data[-1]:
            num_correct += 1
    return num_correct/len(test_db)

pruned_tree = pruneTree(tree, validation, tree)


When I attempt to prune my tree, I am unable to turn a node with two leaves into a single leaf node successfully. I believe when I do node = LeafNode...., it is only a local assignment, so the originaltree does not get pruned, so when i calculate accuracy, it comes back as being equal to the original.

You have to update the tree before computing the new accuracy.
Now you are using the same validation and original_tree to compute the new_accuracy and the current_accuracy.
You can make a copy of the original tree, apply the pruning changes on the copy of the tree, compute the new_accuracy with the updated tree and compare it to the previous accuracy to know if you have to keep the new node or not.

When i call pruneTree, I pass in (tree, validation, tree), so when I update node, i thought it would update the original tree

Your code does not apply the pruning to the original_tree, but instead to the tree passed as the third parameter when calling your function. You can get the pruned tree by doing
pruned_tree = pruneTree(original_tree, validation, original_tree).

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you mean. This is how I call the function
pruned_tree = pruneTree(tree, example_valid, tree)

